# How to restore Bootstrap style in inner div to those inherited from body?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

`inherited from body` has the default bootstrap style inherited from `body` and `div`.

How can I make the inner classes have the exact same style as `inherited from body`, without hard-coding the value used by Bootstrap:

```
<div>inherited from body</div>
<div style="font-size:30px;">
  custom
  <div class="inner">BAD! I want this to have the same style as "inherited from body"</div>
  <div class="inner" style="font-size:16px;">BAD! Same style as "inherited from body", but I don't want to hardcode the value.</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cirosantilli/D2RLR/5626/).

I can use SASS if needed, for example via a mixin that contains all the default styles.

Comment: Not very clear question. The answer would be - add same css class.

Comment: @Morpheus Sorry, which class?  I though TBS added a default style to all elements, even if they have no class. This is what I understood from: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type

Comment: Only one default style is added to all elements by bootstrap (`box-sizing: border-box;`). It's also applied to your inner div. Still don't get the point that styles do you want copy? Would be helpful if you could add a picture or fiddle example.

Comment: I don't mean applied directly: it could also be inherited from body for example. The color was just one example. At http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-body-copy it says for example that: "font-size is 14px, with a line-height of 1.428. This is applied to the <body>". I wanted to apply all the same styles that the exterior div has to the inner div. I'll try to make a fiddle to show better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You just need to set what you changed to `initial` in the CSS for the class `inner`:

   ```
   .inner {
       color: initial;
   }
   ```

   Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUMQe/
2. You could also apply the same `id` to both `<div>`s:

   **HTML**:

   ```
   <div id="same">default</div>
   <div style="color:green; background-color:green;">
       green
       <div class="inner" id="same">inner default</div>
   </div>
   ```

   **CSS**:

   ```
   #same {
       color: #F00;
   }
   ```

   Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUMQe/1/

Comment: Does not `initial` restore the default value for the property as specified by W3C? I want the default specified by Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Initial sets what the default property value is.  For example, the default value for color is `color: #000`.  Therefore, `color: initial` would be equivalent `color: #000`, which matches the other because the color was not changed on the other.

Comment: Did not TBS set the other color to something (in this case white again by coincidence, but it could be something else). This is what I understand from: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type That might be different from what W3C specifies no?

Comment: Well how is the color being applied to the first div?  Is it applied to all divs?

Comment: since TBS says it normalizes the style of all elements, I imagined it was doing something like `body { /*style*/ }`, but I haven't read the source yet.

Comment: I added another possible answer but it depends what you want since this is very vague.

Comment: You can see what it's doing to your divs without reading the source.  Just right-click Inspect both the divs in Chrome or in Firefox, then look at the CSS rules that apply to each of them, to see what the difference is, and to see what you want.

Comment: @joeytwiddle thanks, I use that already. I meant more to find which Less I have to import / include to make it work.